# UFT - Is there a way to look into objects and see what add ins were used while it was added to OR

Tags: object, repository, add-in, qtp

Is there a way to look into objects and see what add ins were used while it was added to OR

The problem I am facing is when I run the script with different add in than what was used to add, it has issues identifying them. We have different Automation tester who have been using more add-in than required and ended up with the issue.

We would need to clean up and re-add only those which are/will be causing trouble and to do that we would need to know if there a way to find from OR what addins were used when we added the objects into them

Comment: Are you referring to local object repositories or shared object repositories?

Comment: Both. Most are in Local Object Repositories but we are eventually merging them to a single Shared Repository. So we would like to clean it up before we merge. But some have already been merged

Answer (score 1):

Since you're primarily talking about the LOR you can look at the test settings and see which addins are associated with the test.

Then in order to see which test object is associated with each addin you can look in the object identification dialog which filters by addin.

[image: object identification dialog]

<sub>Image thanks to [@Vinoth S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897008/vinoth-s).</sub>